# Encrypted sql connection info in webconfig

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Well, I have a website in asp.net 4.5, and I have now started to work with MSSQL, I have puted my connection string in the web-config so I can use it from more then 1 page without writing it down again and again, but then my website manger said I need to encrypt the connection string(so no one will be able to see it.. I guess).

How can I do that? I mean, I have no idea how to encrypt anything, not talking about things like that.

I have search the web for some information but found nothing. sorry if someone already asked it..

Comment: is this really your answer? you should have not answered at all.

Comment: I see my *comment* has been removed. To respond to your *comment*: I didn't answer, I added a *comment* with which I wanted to point you in the right direction of finding an answer yourself. You say you have searched the web and couldn't find anything. I googled once using keywords of your problem and I found multiple results which are exactly what you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Walkthrough: Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)* should help you.

Summary: use the `aspnet_regiis.exe` tool included with .NET on the destination server.